# Dynamics ExecuteMultiple Create followed by Update

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I am trying to leverage the performance increase offered by bundling my requests into an ExecuteMultiple call through the dynamics xrm sdk but am seeing some weird behaviour.

If my first request is a Create request and then I follow it with an Update Request for the entity I have just created (I pre set the Id key on the created entity) then a fault is thrown in the Update Request saying Id not found.

I was under the assumption that these requests were run synchronously and as such, shouldn't the created entity be available when the update request is run?

Comment: Can you post some sample code that is failing?

Comment: Have you checked if the record is created with the Id you specified?

Answer (score 1):

The `ExecuteMultipleRequest` was designed to speed up batch processes. Although this is not documented, I assume this request is processed using parallellism.

I would not recommend to use the `ExecuteMultipleRequest` in common transacted scenarios, because a maximum of only two requests can be processed at the same time. So, this request does not scale very well. (Refer to MSDN: [Use ExecuteMultiple to improve performance for bulk data load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj863631.aspx).)

Instead use the `ExecuteTransactionRequest`. (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executetransactionrequest.aspx).) With this request it *is* possible to mix create and update requests in the way you need.

Comment: I think the MSDN suggest parallelism is not used. `ExecuteMultipleRequest accepts an input collection of message Requests, executes each of the message requests in the order they appear in the input collection` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj863631.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the ExecuteTransactionRequest as I have to provide a solution that works with the 2011 sdk, however you're point about only have a maximum of 2 is very valid and as such it may be more beneficial to use an OrganizationServiceContext instead and build up the entity structure and perform a single savechanges. I'm not sure how efficient that will be though

Comment: @doodlleus: `OrganizationServiceContext` is not likely to give you performance gains, because `SaveChanges` just issues all pending create/update/delete operations one by one. You can speed up the operation considerably though when you implement parallellism.